# I added a large dictionary (10,000 items) to my code and now the ipa has been archiving for half an hour

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

My app includes a function that counts syllables in words entered by the user.  There's a large dictionary of about 10,000 exceptions to the rules in the syllable checker, and now that I'm archiving the ipa for the first time after adding the dictionary, things have slowed down a lot.  Previous ipas have archived in several seconds.  Now I've been stuck on "Compiling 4 of 28 source files" for the last half hour.  The code looks like this:

```
 NSDictionary *exceptions = @{
@"simile" : @3,
@"forever" : @3,
@"shoreline" : @2,
@"poetry" : @3,
    };
// if one of the preceding words, return special case value
NSNumber *caught = exceptions[lowercase];
if (caught) {
    return caught.integerValue;
}
```

Is such a long archive time normal?  If not, should I approach this differently?  Load the dictionary from a plist, perhaps?

Comment: You may want to consider some server options. For one, when people try to download your app, it's going to take an extremely long time for them to download. Also, your app is likely going to take up a ludicrous amount of space on the user's device.

Comment: Do you mean that the exceptions dictionary should be stored on a server and the app should check against it online?  Or that the app should download the dictionary once it's already installed?

Comment: The first one. I obviously don't know specifics of your app, but there shouldn't be any need - that I can think of - to have a ginormous dictionary on a device as opposed to a server.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, part of the app involves the user writing haiku, which are poems of three lines of 5 syllables, 7 syllables, and 5 syllables, and there's an option for the app to check whether the user has used the correct number of syllables.  So if somebody's writing a haiku on the subway, and the syllable checker exceptions are only available online, s/he might get things marked wrong that are actually correct....  But that's probably not worth a huge size.

Comment: Though it looks like I can probably cut the list by a third, if not by half.  If somebody gets marked wrong for the word "daoust," I'm okay with that.

Comment: Okay, well I would advise creating a really crafty algorithm for it, or a mixture of dictionaries & an algorithm. After what you said, I would actually agree and say that you should make it work natively.

Comment: I would go here and hire one of these guys: http://www.wired.com/magazine/2010/11/mf_algorithmolympics/ haha

Comment: No, such a long archive time is not normal.  10,000 words really isn't that much when it comes to code....

Comment: Can the data be stored *outside* of code? (SQLite, extensible hash, xml, etc?) That is, remove it from the compilation process entirely: it would also likely make it easier to support different languages.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing--putting the data into a plist and loading it from there.  It doesn't seem to have added much to the size of the app.